# The binary format for different data types

Tags: c++, c, bit, shift

What is the exact binary format of a `unsigned long long` type (at least in visual studio).

I am doing some bit-wise operation with aliasing pointers, I set the bit through operations on `unsigned char` pointers then doing some other operations on `unsigned long long` pointers(alias).

The format of `unsigned long long` looks weird and because of this, it mess up the results, also, it seems that the bit-shift operation also behave strangely:

From bit-mask test it seems that this data is arranged from `right: LSB->MSB : left`, which means a >> shift will take the data to its more significant bit instead of the less ones, is this correct?

The compiler being ICC 13.0, and the OS is windows 7-64.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is in order.

Comment: Is it possible that you are doing pointer trickery (casting to `char*`) to extract single bytes? In this case, your confusion probably comes from endianness issues.

Comment: I use unsigned char * to set bits and aliasing pointers to handle other maths ops, it seems it mess things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The byte layout you describe is little endian, which is the layout that Intel processors use in general. Bit shifts don't depend on the memory layout of the number, but rather the value, so endianness should not impact the value of your operations. If you are using pointer aliasing, however, like casting to a `char *` and using pointer arithmetic to extract segments of it, you will get endianness-dependent behaviour which, on little endian Intel processors, might not be what you were expecting.

Comment: If you want to extract individual bytes without caring about endianness you can do a shift-and-mask operation, like `(x >> 16) & 0xff` to get the third-lowest-order byte.

Comment: Is there some serious performance hit invovled here by doing this, thanks. The main reason why there are several aliasing pointers here are for performance benefits,  I can use 64 bit-wide data type instead (if necessary).

Comment: I highly doubt you'll notice a difference, and the compiler will probably optimize it regardless. Have you actually noticed the need for that kind of optimization?

Comment: @user0002128: "I can use 64 bit-wide data type instead"... if you care about performance, profile.  I'd be surprised if it was any slower (it may well be faster) to filter out specific bits (using `&` and a compile time constant mask) from a 64 bit value and test for 0/non-zero than to do some filter/tests on an 8-bit slice.  Same for setting bits with `|=`.  I think you're in premature-optimisation quicksand.

Comment: @Tony D: sure, thats a last resort, the reason why I stick to unsigned char is for faster bit-wise set/access, I am now just change my code to meet the little-endian, so it is OK for now, as for why 64-bit, well, for bit-sum, 64 bit wide data is faster since there are several SIMD instructions for such tasks, and a 256-bit alias for SIMDed bitwise logical operations.

Comment: @user0002128 "the reason why I stick to unsigned char is for faster bit-wise set/access": have you *measured* it being faster? What I'm saying is I suspect it'll be SLOWER, and even if not slower, probably just the same.

Comment: @Tony D: I dont think you get the point: First of all, unsigned char * can be aliasing to any other type so it come for free, second, have a unsigned char * type is indeed faster, since with unsigned-char you can access values from bit field through look-up table whilst a uint64 type look-up type will take size_t size level memory to store.

Comment: All in all, the bit-field library I wrote is about several times faster than the one in boost, let alone the poor bit-field functions in the standard C++, and it offer far richer functionalities, so I guess I have some practical optimzation experience here.